# MatLab: parfeval() doesn't call function

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, background

I am trying to process Data from an UDP Server close to realtime.

For that I wrote this MatLab Code to fill a Buffer with the UDP Datagrams and Process the Data (split the strings, etc.) once the Buffer from my MatLab function is full (myBuffer).

During Processing the data (which takes about 0.9s) I need to go on receiving Data and store them in the (now) emptied Buffer.

I found the parfeval-Function of the "Parallel Computing Toolbox" which might suit my needs as I need my function "ProcessData" to run in the background.

The Problem I encountered is that I can't make it run as the parfeval function doesn't enter my function ProcessData. I tested it with setting a breakpoint in ProcessData() but the program never stops. Did I do anything wrong with the function parameters?

That's what MatLab help says: F = parfeval(p,fcn,numout,in1,in2,...) requests asynchronous execution of the function fcn on a worker contained in the parallel pool p, expecting numout output arguments and supplying as input arguments in1,in2,....

Hope you guys can help me with this problem! Thanks in advance.

```
function ReadVoltage

    %% Specify a Server (host name or IP address) with Port 8080
    u = udp('192.168.0.164', 8080);  %UDP Object Zuhause
    %u = udp('169.254.38.221', 8080);  %UDP Object Pilotfabrik    

    % Buffer in the enclosing function
    myBuffer = {};  %Initialisierung
    MAXBUFFLEN = 100; %Maximale Anzahl an Eintraegen in Buffer (1 Eintrage = 1 Datagram)

    u.InputBufferSize = 4060; 
    u.ReadAsyncMode = 'continuous';
    u.DatagramReceivedFcn = @DatagramReceivedFcn;
    u.ErrorFcn = @ErrorFcn;
    u.DatagramTerminateMode = 
    u.Terminator = '!';

    %% Initialize Parallel pool 
    pool = gcp();

    %% Oeffnen der Verbindung
    fopen(u);

     if (~strcmp(u.Status,'open'))
         NetworkError(u,'Connection failed!');
     end


    %% Start Data transmission by trigger
    fprintf(u, 'Requesting Data')

    %% Callback Funktion
    function DatagramReceivedFcn(u,~) 

        datagram = fscanf(u);
        disp('Data Received!');


        myBuffer{end+1} = datagram;         %Appends datagram to buffer


        [~, bufflen] = size(myBuffer);

        if bufflen < MAXBUFFLEN
            return;
        else
            f = parfeval(pool, @ProcessData, 1, myBuffer);
            myBuffer = {};               %empty Buffer
        end 

    end

    function ErrorFcn(u,~) 
        disp("An Error occured");
    end

end

function datagram_values = ProcessData(myBuffer)


    stringvalues = split(myBuffer, ";");        %Split Strings
    doublevalues = str2double(stringvalues)     %Convert Strings do Doubles

    dim_doublevalues = size(doublevalues);      %Dimension of Double Output Array

    i_max = dim_doublevalues(2)                 %Anzahl der Datenpakete
    j_max = (dim_doublevalues(3))-1             %Anzahl der Werte pro Datenpaket; -1 wegen leerem Wert nach ";" am Ende
    k_max = i_max*j_max                         %Gesamtanzahl der Werte in Buffer

    k=1;
    while k<=k_max
        for i = 1:i_max
            for j = 1:j_max
                    datagram_values(k,1)=doublevalues(1,i,j);
                    k=k+1;
            end
        end
    end

    disp(datagram_values);


end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the MATLAB debugger can't stop in code running on the workers - only code running at the client.

In this case, you should try looking at the diary output of the future `f`, like this:

```
f = parfeval(...);
wait(f); % wait for the worker to complete
disp(f.Diary); % display the output
```

If you don't wish to block the client, you could use [`afterEach`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/parallel.future.aftereach.html) to invoke the call to `disp`, like this:

```
f = parfeval(...);
afterEach(f, @(f) disp(f.Diary), 0, 'PassFuture', true);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This explains why the breakpoints didn't work. 

As I receive the expected output with f.Diary, I assume my function is working as expected.

So if I want to include an sqlwrite statement at the end of my ProcessData function, it should process and write the data to a DB while my program is going on receiving UDP datagrams, correct? (without using wait(f) & disp(f.Diary))

Comment: Yes, whatever's happening on the worker will continue and leave the client free. You might next wish to look into `parallel.pool.Constant` if you want to have each worker hold on to a persistent database connection (see the doc page for details).

Comment: Thanks for your support! I will have a look at it but probably not need it yet as all the data should be written to one database :)

Comment: One other question:
In case my parfeval function did not finish processing the data from myBuffer before the next Buffer is passed to the function - Will it directly distributed to one of the other 12 workers in the pool? In case it's not, what's the best practice to avoid such a situation?

Comment: The `parfeval` requests will run in parallel on your available workers, and they are sent to workers in the order that you call `parfeval`.

Comment: Okey great, so I can process 12 datagrams parallel (with 12 workers in my case) before a 13th one is passed. As i think that there should be a maximum of 2 or 3 parallel it shouldn't be a problem. Thanks - you helped a lot!